# Laying down Fescue sod in North Carolina in Late October. good idea?

Tags: lawn, lawn-repair

I just scheduled a pallet of Fescue sod to delivered to my home for Wednesday. The salesman said that Fescue sod is only sod that will grow/root throughout the winter if laid down now. Is this correct? Is fescue the only sod to lay down at this time of year?

Also, he said that I will need to overseed the Fescue grass area next spring. Can I overseed with a variety/mix of grass? Or only Fescue?

Thanks, many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Piedmont, it is best to plant fescue in the fall.  It then has a chance to get established in the late fall and winter, before the arrival of next spring's warmth.

I live in Chapel Hill, NC.

Comment: Thanks. I laid down 2 pallets of fescue and the roots have set. I realize I'm going to have some challenges in the summer. I plan on feeding and overseeding in the spring.

Answer (score 1):

With some additional information, it appears that the salesman gave me good advice.

http://www.fescue.com/info/whentoplant.html

Fescue is a cool weather grass, and it is best to plant it in the fall and spring. Down in north carolina, it would be practically impossible to plant it in the summer months due to the heat.

The salesman was also correct that Fescue grass/sod, even when established, does not fare well in summer (in NC), and it would be advisable to overseed in the spring.  When I do overseed, I plan on overseeding with a grass mix.